# Draping vector data over DTM in Oracle?

Tags: dem, software-recommendations, oracle-spatial

I have ~100 million 2d vector topographic features (lines and polygons) in an Oracle 12c database.
I have 20 billion xyz points in an Oracle database table as number types - the points cover the same geographic area as the 2d vector data.
I want to height the 2d vector data based on the xyz point data - i.e. in practice this would probably involve creating a TIN based on the xyz points and then draping the 2d vector data over this.

Bearing in the mind the quantity of data involved, what technology options are there to perform this task?